# XAML changes without effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to put a textblock in a grid element, but it doesn't display in the debug mode. What do I do wrong? Maybe it's caused that I manipulate the window directly by my C# code?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication2;component/Images/Grass0118_22_S.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Życia:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin="50,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=points}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you provide relevant code? And some specific details about your problem?

Comment: The code attached above.

Comment: If you manipulat the window in code behind, why don't you add that as well?

Comment: Because of working with XAML is easier than doing it directly by C# code, right?

Comment: I meant that you should just post any code relevant to the question. Do not post answers inside the question, post them as actual answer and accept them.

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer own question yet. I must wait about 7 hours :).

Comment: @daroPL: Really? I didn't know about that limitation, only knew about not being able to accept it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved my issue. 
I had defined a canvas tag in my C# code and it overwrote the XAML changes. I replaced the XAML code to the following

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication2;component/Images/Grass0118_22_S.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Canvas>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Życia:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Margin="50,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=points}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Canvas Name="mycanvas"></Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

and removed the line creating the canvas element from my C# code and everything works now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Grid>
    <Stackpanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">Życia:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin="50,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=points}"></TextBlock>

  </Stackpanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: It's the same. I suppose elements set up by the C# code overwrite the XAML items. What do you think about that?